# What would be the best approach to retrieve the shape of JSON files loaded from a TypeScript async function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

From the following example:

```
export type AppMessages = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof loadMessages>>;

export type Locale = "en" | "fr" | "es";

export const loadMessages = async (locale: Locale) => ({
  foo: locale === 'en' 
    ? (await import('../../messages/en/foo.json')).default 
    : (await import(`../../messages/${locale}/foo.json`)).default
});
```

All JSON files have the same shape, however the `AppMessages` type is resolved as

```
type AppMessages = {
    foo: any;
}
```

I thought about this solution:

```
export type AppMessages = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof loadDefaultMessages>>;

export type Locale = "en" | "fr" | "es";

const loadDefaultMessages = async () => ({
  foo: (await import("../../messages/en/foo.json")).default,
});

const loadLocaleMessages = async (locale: Locale): Promise<AppMessages> => ({
  foo: (await import(`../../messages/${locale}/foo.json`)).default,
});

export const loadMessages = async (locale: AppLanguages) =>
  locale === "en"
    ? await loadDefaultMessages()
    : await loadLocaleMessages(locale);
```

Which has the `AppMessages` type correctly shaped, however this solution will lead to a lot of repetitions and potential code duplications.

Is there a better solution yielding the same result, that is having `AppMessages` be shaped according to the JSON data files. Manually setting the `AppMessages` type is not an option.

Comment: I don't get the `locale === 'en'` condition. Why not just omit that?

Comment: @Bergi because TS cannot infer types from the template string used in the import statement. I tried solving this by providing a default value for it.

Answer (score 1):

Only you (can) know that all the `foo.json` files in any of those directories will (or at least should) have the exact same shape as the one in the */en/* directory. So you must tell TypeScript:

```
type FooMessages = (typeof import("../../messages/en/foo.json"))["default"];
```

then

```
export type AppMessages = { foo: FooMessages; }

export type Locale = "en" | "fr" | "es";

export async function loadMessages(locale: Locale): Promise<AppMessages> {
  return {
    foo: (await import(`../../messages/${locale}/foo.json`)).default,
  };
}
```

Comment: Oh! that's a good start, then the `loadMessages` can use arguments. However, this slight change works for me : `type FooMessages = typeof import("../../messages/en/foo.json");`